# How to configure localhost on Linux?

Tags: linux, centos7, host

I'm trying to set up a virtual machine with CentOS 7 to use it as an Oracle Database Server (I'm new to Linux). I have encountered a problem about the host configuration that as I was reading has to be configured previously.

You see, this is where I collide with my knowledge that I have in windows. I thought it was enough to change the device name like this:

```
[root@localhost.localdomain ~] # hostname SERVER01
[root@localhost.localdomain ~] # hostname
SERVER01
[root @ SERVER01 ~] #
```

And I do not understand why from windows I can not `ping` the Linux machine only using its hostname (`SERVER01`)

```
The ping request could not find host SERVER01. Check the name and
try again.
```

I understand that the previous configuration of the host in `CentOS 7` that I am asked to install the database server has to do with the fact that I can not `ping` it using `SERVER01`. Although I have to clarify that using the IP if I can.

What do I do to make that change in Linux and can `ping` only using the hostname as it happens in windows?

Comment: Are you trying to ping the linux virtual box from your Windows command prompt?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking questions about programming problems that, preferably, involve code. Your question is off topic because it involves Linux and server configuration, both of which should be asked on either https://serverfault.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you change the `hostname` in linux you are essentially just telling the OS "this is your name".

In order to reflect that on the network mapping as well, you need to edit the *hosts* file:

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

or if you are a vi fan:

```
vi /etc/hosts
```

Note that you will need root access to do this.

In that file you can just extend the localhost mapping to also include your custom hostname `SERVER01`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost SERVER01
```

Once you do this, from the same CentOS terminal you can type `ping SERVER01` and it should give you a proper ping results.

If you want to be able to ping and access the services on that virtual machine from your Windows OS, then you will need to do the same mapping through the *hosts* file on your Windows, but this time you will have to use the IP provided to the vm, instead of *127.0.0.1*.

Comment: Please avoid answering [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) fodder. Instead, close it and move on. It is sometimes helpful to suggest a site where the question may be on-topic.

Comment: thanks!! I have configured it the same, only I have removed the localhost.localdomain. How important is it?

Comment: You should be fine, its not that important ;)